# Temporarily set non-iCloud password; now both temporary and iCloud passwords required at startup

Tags: macos, password, filevault, startup

My Yosemite MacBook Pro is normally set to use my iCloud password. Taking it in for service to the Apple store, they suggested I create a temporary password, which I did by going to Users & Groups -> my user, clicking Change Password, and clicking "Use Separate Password".

On restart I noticed I was prompted twice for passwords. The first time, the temporary password did not work and I had to use my iCloud password. The second prompt (following a progress bar) required my new temporary password.

The technician did their stuff, and then I went back to my user, Change Password, and back to using my iCloud password. On restart, again was prompted twice. The first time required my temporary password, the second time, my iCloud password. OK - this fits the pattern: change your password, and your old pw will still be in effect for this first of two authentications.

However, on subsequent restarts it continues to require authenticating twice, and the temporary password now appears to be "stuck" as the one required for the first authentication - which I understand is possibly Filevault.

So in other words:

- restart
- select my user
- authenticate using non-iCloud temporary password
- some loading occurs
- select my user again
- authenticate using iCloud password

Is there a way to get the first authentication "back" to using my iCloud password?

I suppose I could "Use Separate Password" again and use my actual iCloud password, then back to using iCloud to sign in. At least then both pws will (maybe) be the same. But if there is a "righter" way of doing this I'd rather do that.